# Can I use ArrayList in a class which extends Thread?

Tags: java, android, arraylist

Is it possible to use an `ArrayList` within a class that extends `Thread`? I have written some code to read from Bluetooth serial which was working, but I've added an `ArrayList` to keep track of what I'm reading. However I'm getting `NullPointException` on any line that accesses *results*.
I know that `ArrayList` is not thread safe (although I may not understand fully what that means) so I may be trying to do impossible things but I thought I would check with the experts as ArrayLists are otherwise very easy to work with.

```
private class ConnectedThread extends Thread {
    private final BluetoothSocket mmSocket;
    private final InputStream mmInStream;
    private List<String> results;

    public ConnectedThread(BluetoothSocket socket) {
        Log.d(TAG, "create ConnectedThread");
        mmSocket = socket;
        InputStream tmpIn = null;
        OutputStream tmpOut = null;
        List<String> results = new ArrayList<String>();

        // Get the BluetoothSocket input and output streams
        try {
            tmpIn = socket.getInputStream();
            tmpOut = socket.getOutputStream();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "temp sockets not created", e);
        }

        mmInStream = tmpIn;
        mmOutStream = tmpOut;

        init();
    }

    private void init(){
        code = new byte[16];
        checksum = 0;
        tempbyte = 0;
        bytesread = -1;
        if(!results.isEmpty()){
            Log.i(TAG, "Already have found: " + results.size() + " things.");
        }
    }

    public void run(){
       //do things
    }
}
```

Comment: @PatriciaShanahan in the constructor

Comment: "Is it possible to use an ArrayList within a class that extends Thread?" In the abstract: yes, of course it is.

Comment: Thank you all for the comments, they were all helpful but ofc I can choose only 1 answer. I'm not so used to Java but I now fully understand what I was doing wrong.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In your constructor, you have created a local ArrayList reference with the same name as instance ArrayList, and initializing that.

```
List<String> results = new ArrayList<String>();  // This creates a local arraylist
```

So, your instance `ArrayList` reference is still `null`. Change that line to:

```
results = new ArrayList<String>();
```

Answer (score 1):

This line

```
List<String> results = new ArrayList<String>();
```

is allocating an array list on a *local* variable `results`.  You probably think it's allocating the class member.  Try changing to

```
results = new ArrayList<String>();
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem you have is that you are not initializing your instance variable but only  a local variable with the same name.

Remove the List before result in your constructor.

Answer (score 0):

```
this.results = results; //do this in constructor
```